# Understanding passing an iterable to python's all

Tags: python

using `all`, I understand this for example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
all([n > 0 for n in l])
```

all takes an iterable, all good.

how come this works (no square brackets, no list comprehension):

`all(n > 0 for n in l)`

but this doesn't work (calling it without `all`):

`n > 0 for n in l` (SyntaxError)

and obviously, this works:

`[n > 0 for n in l]`

What's happening when calling any, why is it taking `n > 0 for n in l` as an iterable?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not just `all`, all function will interpret such parenthesis-less ones as generator if that's the only parameter they got, to quote from [Python Document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) - *"The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument."*

Comment: @jupiterbjy - this was super clear and explains everything. can you write it as an answer? thanks!

Comment: Seems like people are quite confused about whether to flag this as duplicate or not! You found your answer so that's all what matters to me. Happy python!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing [a generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), and generators are iterable

The same could be done as

```
gen = (n > 0 for n in l)
print(all(gen))
```

> and obviously, this works

That's a list comprehension, and not really relevant to the problem. Passing it to the all function needlessly creates an in-memory list, and thus will iterate the list more than once - one to create, and one to test all elements

Comment: If you call it ["generator expression"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), it is closer to the terminology. They were introduced in [PEP 289](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/).

Comment: @glglgl well, no, this was already correct, if we are not speaking informally. A generator expression evaluates to a generator object, which is what is passed. Passing an *expression* sounds like more esoteric evaluation strategies like *call by name*

Comment: I think this answers half the question. While you are correct, there is a distinction between list comprehension and generators, it does not explain why `n > 0 for n in l` throws a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I don't see the need to explain invalid syntax since the Python documentation explains the syntax perfectly fine on its own. What exactly is the expression supposed to be evaluated to?

Comment: If I were to type `"""Testing"""` on a new line, Python does not complain. However, if I type `_ for _ in []` on a new line, Python starts complaining. Why is this? Both the string and the generator are objects, why does Python only throw an error on the latter?

Comment: @Xiddoc why would it complain about a string? It complains about `_ for _ in []` because that does not adhere to the [the syntax rules for generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

Comment: The interpreter parses the string, and doesn't know how to handle the other expression without surrounding brackets or parenthesis, as it's not valid syntax

Comment: TIL generators need parentheses... thanks!